# Perl miss and hit with cookie grabber

Tags: perl, cookies

Bellow is a script which grabs a cookie from "example.com" and encodes it base64, 
It usually works, although for some reason I will have random days where it acts up and does not grab any cookies at all.
I've checked myself at times where the script was failing, and the site would still send a cookie to the client.

Same method, nothing changed on the sites behalf, and nothing would change on the script, though it would still just act up some times.

Anyone know what this could possibly be?

Do I have to change my method of grabbing cookies incase this method may be obsolete or ancient?

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->cookie_jar({});
use Data::Dumper;
$ua->get("http://www.example.com");
my $cookie = encode_base64($ua->cookie_jar->as_string);
```

Other info: It's apart of a perl cgi script, hosted on a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unsure of the error thats causing this, Although, when I had turned off "CloudFlare" for my website, the problem resolved itself immediately.
Oh well there goes 3 hours of my life over CloudFlare...